# RotateX and RotateY at on hover do not work at firefox and IE. Alternatives

Tags: html, css, firefox, transform

In these browsers:

- Opera
- Safari
- Chrome

separate rotate works.

But in *Firefox* it rotate elements in 2 steps.

I wonder how I can replace this - maybe with *rotate3d* or *matrix3d*.

Currently I am using **CSS** as:

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
perspective: 1200px;
```

And dynamically change transform with **JS**:

```
transformPoster = ' rotateX(' + (-offsetY * offsetPoster) + 'deg) rotateY(' + (offsetX * (offsetPoster )) + 'deg) '; //poster transform
```

Here's my [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/Zentro/pen/ZONQPB?editors=0010#0) for a better understanding, check this in *Firefox*

Comment: I have tested your *Codepen* but didn't find any abrupt behavior in animation on any browser you have mentioned here.

Comment: Ditto. The Codepen works fine in my Firefox (47.0.1 on OS X 10.11.6). It does look jerky on IE11 running inside VirtualBox but still somewhat similar to real browsers.

Comment: Checked in Firefox: 47, 48. On video you can see how it twitches. So I think I need to try different approach. https://monosnap.com/file/bDVVjNLmILHXzkV65zmjxti3GW4Rdr.